# can we get LaTeX formatting for equations in questions and answers on homebrewing?

Tags: feature-request

a'la [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)?

I feel like there's enough discussion of homebrew calculations on here that it might be beneficial.

Some examples:

- [Calculating Alcohol by Volume](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/calculating-alcohol-by-volume)
- [How do you convert between SRM and Lovibond?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-you-convert-between-srm-and-lovibond)
- one of the answers in [Beer calculators and batch/boil size with late fermentable additions](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3634/beer-calculators-and-batch-boil-size-with-late-fermentable-additions)

Comment: Start by compiling a list of questions where it would be beneficial. We need to see some examples. :)

Comment: If no one has mentioned it before, having Latex on the site really really decreases load time, so unless you see it being useful quite often then you may want to forgo it as it will cause people googling to not see the snappy load time as normally associated with SE. It is still fast, but it can be quite slow compared to what other SE sites can pull.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ambivalent on it.

I'll use them if the formatting options are there, and will make do without them if not.

Comment: I think I'm with you. The syntax is not necessarily straightforward for those who aren't used to working in LaTeX, so I definitely wouldn't expect universal adoption. Most formulas here are simple enough to not need it, but some of them get ugly. A benevolent editor could clean these up if the LaTeX tools were available.

Comment: yeah, I think that it would end up on the shoulders of some benevolent editor.